# NodeGit fileHistoryWalk doesn't show merge commit

Tags: merge, commit, gitkraken, nodegit

I found that when I used 'fileHistoryWalk' for a file.

The result showed the last commit is red one rather then blue one.

[image]

also the merge commit between red and blue didn't show, either.

How can I really know the all commit about a file including merge commit?

I am sure the merge commit (blue one) is modified my file which I wanted to focus.

I also know that when you see the file history in gitKraken. It doesn't show either.

Thanks

https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/issues/1531

Comment: Changes in merge commits are not always shown in a files' history. I've encountered this before, and it seems to be due to which branch is considered first and second parent for a merge; since changes in GK are only shown relative to the first branch. Are the merge commits shown if you use `git log` or `gitk` via command line to show the files history?

Comment: Yes, `git log` show the correct message. I decide to change my user scenario. Thanks your comment .